# Group BY in SELECT CASE SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by, select-case

hi i have a query that return YES or NOT for each user now in result i want to add StudentId for showing better result how i can do this?

```
WITH Prev AS
(
    SELECT StudentId, ISNULL(SUM(Score),0) As HighScoreUser
FROM (SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_ActPoint
UNION ALL
      SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_EvaPoint     WHERE Date>='1396/01/01' and Date <= '1396/01/31'
      ) as T 
      GROUP BY  StudentId
),
Cur AS 
(
    SELECT StudentId, ISNULL(SUM(Score),0) As HighScoreUser
FROM (SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_ActPoint
UNION ALL
      SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_EvaPoint     WHERE Date>'1396/02/01' and Date <= '1396/02/31'
      ) as T 
      GROUP BY  StudentId
)
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN(Prev.HighScoreUser <= Cur.HighScoreUser)
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END as HaveGift
FROM Prev
INNER JOIN Cur
ON Prev.StudentId = Cur.StudentId
```

[image]

Comment: add Prev.StudentId, on the last select, before "CASE"

Comment: what is your input dataset and what is your expected output?

Comment: tnx bro, @Backs answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Just add column:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN(Prev.HighScoreUser <= Cur.HighScoreUser)
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END as HaveGift,
        Prev.StudentId
FROM Prev
INNER JOIN Cur
ON Prev.StudentId = Cur.StudentId
```